# Storing oauth tokens from other API in backend database

Tags: android, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, backend

I'm developing system witch should get data from fitbit API every day. I want to download their data regardless they were online. Could I store users access and refresh tokens in my backend database? Is it secure enough or are there better solution?

Update: My app has own auth system. I only need to get users data every day.